# NSString stringWithFormat can't add backslash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm calling a webService using AFNetWorking and want to pass a parameter of this shape,

**112212234234324@abcdefghi_def.ab\/AB**

and to achieve that i'm using following code,

```
@{@"someKey":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@\/AB", someTextField.text, [aDictionary objectForKey:@"someOtherKey"]]};
```

But stringWithFormat is ignoring backslash and value for someKey is,

**112212234234324@abcdefghi_def.ab/AB**

I've also tried this,

```
@{@"someKey":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@\\/AB", someTextField.text, [aDictionary objectForKey:@"someOtherKey"]]};
```

but it won't treat double slash as single slash and someKey value is,

**112212234234324@abcdefghi_def.ab\\/AB**

NSLog is converting fine.

`NSLog(@"\\");` gives \

`NSLog(@"\\\\");` gives \\

`NSLog(@"\\/");` gives \/

Please help.

Comment: go down the rabbit hole, see how it's processed inside the library.

Comment: did you log value by NSLog, you did true when use @"\\/" but in NSLog it's will show wrong value. Try print value of dictionary[@"someKey"], and this string length to debug value in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 @{@"someKey":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@%@/AB", someTextField.text, [aDictionary objectForKey:@"someOtherKey"],@"\\"]};
```

Comment: i can't see \ in this. Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it by skipping `\`. After discussing with backend team, i came to know that backslash will be ignored anyways by parser so it isn't needed.

Updated code looks like,

```
@{@"someKey":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@/AB", someTextField.text, [aDictionary objectForKey:@"someOtherKey"]]};
```

Comment: So generally an impossible question for anyone to answer and of no value to anyone else.